# How to fix an Exception Notification error, and send a letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I send a letter to Postoffice through the [Exception Notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) gem there is an error, and a letter is not sent in production:

```
Error: An error occurred when sending a notification using 'email' notifier. Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 <example@exmple.com>, Recipient unknown
```

Locally through [Letter Opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) everything works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's [Postoffice](https://github.com/chrisbutcher/postoffice)  and not [postman](https://github.com/moomerman/postman)?

> ## Postoffice
>
> Rails gem to validate format of various world postal and zip codes,

If it's postman you should look in your production.rb:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
...

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => '25', # or 2525
  :address        => ENV['POSTMARK_SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name      => ENV['POSTMARK_API_TOKEN'],
  :password       => ENV['POSTMARK_API_TOKEN'],
  :domain         => 'example.com',
  :authentication => :cram_md5, # or :plain for plain-text authentication
  :enable_starttls_auto => true, # or false for unencrypted connection
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

...
```

Comment: I added this line `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail`  and it worked, thanks

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help :)